# Highlight titlebar only when mouse is over?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

I want to implement a titlebar experience just like the iBooks app on OS X. Basically, the titlebar is always *not highlight* even if the window is key window right now. However, it did has the cute *fade in* like animation that paints the titlebar.

I'm wondering how to implement this kind of window titlebar?

My first guess if leveraging [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow), and handle the mouse entered and mouse exited event? But I don't find out how to dim the titlebar, and how to fade in.

So any suggestions for this?